# SSL/TLS Handshake error while calling Azure Vision API

Tags: spring-boot, azure, computer-vision, ssl-certificate, containers

I have a spring boot based microservice in which I am using Microsoft Azure Computer Vision API to read data from a PDF file. After containerizing the microservice, the container works fine and I am able to send/receive data to/from Computer Vision API on my machine. But, when I run this container on an Azure based Linux Virtual Machine, the container cannot communicate with the Computer Vision API and throws exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error`. Also, the spring-boot jar is able to communicate with Azure on VM and throws no such exception.

Do you think I need to pass any self-signed certificate to the container for it to be able to communicate smoothly?

I think the biggest advantage of using these containers is that it makes the code platform independent. So, why is this error thrown only on Azure VM and runs completely fine on my machine? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out what the error was. There was nothing wrong with the JDK/JRE setup. The issue arose due to the version of docker engine installed on the Azure VM.

Azure based computer vision APIs required server to be TLS1.2 compliant, whereas the version of the docker engine installed on my machine was older and did not support TLS1.2. I was able to fix it after upgrading the docker engine to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: RSA premaster secret error
```

On local computer was working fine but when run the container on Azure Linux VM it is not working so there might be compatibility issue between Linux VM and Java JRE’s.
Based on above error the solution is Just remove the updated java version from your server Classpath and try to install the old java version

Please refer this link had the same discussion over here related to above error : https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1533888/another-rsa-premaster-secret-error

Second, try to set the SSL/TLS parameters in the java panel because An SSL certificate is a bit of code on your web server that provides security for online communications. When a web browser contacts your secured website, the SSL certificate enables an encrypted connection. It's kind of like sealing a letter in an envelope before sending it through the mail.

[Supported SSL/TLS versions by JDK version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/jdk-tls-versions.html#jdk-tls-versions)